# Couldn't find what is the right permission for accessing feeds from a closed facebook group

Tags: node.js, facebook

I am trying to read feeds in a closed facebook group using nodejs.

what I did:

Created a facebook app with the following scope `['user_posts','manage_pages', 'groups_access_member_info']`, and got it installed by one of the member of that closed group, and now by using `[fbgraph][1]` module on my express server trying to get the feeds from that group. The response I am getting is

> "(#200) Requires either admin permissions or member using installed
>   app."

Can any one let me know if I am missing any permissions or doing it the wrong way? Please, suggest me if there is another way of getting feeds out of closed facebook groups.

Comment: Can you add a snippet ?

Comment: just found my issue it seems my app is not added to the group first. Thank you.